# Detecting Click In Coordinates of Rectangle with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want my code to detect and trigger a custom function when user click within the coordinates of a rectangular.

IF the coordinates of Rectangle are already know.

I tried this code

```
W = $(el).width();
   H = $(el).height();
   X = $(el).position().left;
   Y = $(el).position().top;
```

But not able to detect it.

Example

Consider this. 
I want to detect and trigger function within these coordinates.

http://www.mathopenref.com/coordrectangle.html

Getting mouse coordinates is easy:-

```
$('canvas').mousemove(function(e){
    drawPaddle(e.pageX, e.pageY);
});


function drawPaddle(paddleX, paddleY) {
    c.beginPath();
    c.rect(paddleX, paddleY, 150, 10);
    c.closePath();
    c.fill();
}
```

How do I detect if user click within coordinates of my rectangle?

Comment: `jQuery('image').click(function() { // do something })`

Comment: @Alp, I don't want to trigger function on image click. I need to use Coordinates of image for similar functionality.

Comment: I do not understand what you want to do with that coordinates. Please update your question with more information.

Comment: You need to get mouse coordinates too and after click check if mouse is inside rectangle.

Comment: Just Edited my question as required.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
var mouseX;
var mouseY;


$(el).mousemove(function(e){
    mouseX = e.pageX;
    mouseY = e.pageY;
});

$(el).click(function(e)
{
    W = $(el).width();
    H = $(el).height();
    X = $(el).position().left;
    Y = $(el).position().top;

    if (mouseX>X   && 
        mouseY>Y   && 
        mouseX<X+W && 
        mouseY<Y+H)
    {
        //do something
    }
});
```

It might need some adjustments though...

Answer (score 0):

You can check the mouse position directly on the click event. Just compare that to your rectangle coordinates.

```
$(document).mousedown(function(e) {
   var x = e.pageX;
   var y = e.pageY; 

    if((x >= X && x <= X+W) &&
       (y >= Y && y <= Y+H))
        alert("in");
});

var el = "#div1";
var W = $(el).width();
var H = $(el).height();
var X = $(el).position().left;
var Y = $(el).position().top;
```

Check out my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/styson/PxcBs/1/).

Comment: Problem is, i don't know how to compare the two. This i already know.